# bx-slider is behaving unexpected when on 320px

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider, responsive

I have a carousel with 5 images of 240 by 300 pixels. When I resize my window to 320px and navigate to the 3 image. the images jump 3 positions and start from there. Meaning I see image 1, image 2, image3 jumping to image 1, image 2 and image 3, and when I move further he resets to the first image again.

I happens both in Chrome and Firefox.
Does anybody know why he behaves like this? Is it because the combination of settings?

```
<div class="Carousel">
<ul auto="false" class="bxslider" marginslide="5" minslide="5" mode="horizontal" moveslide="0" navigation="true" pager="false" pause="4000" playstop="true" random="false" speed="500">
<li><a href="/page1"> <img src="image1.jpg" title="title  "/></a></li>
<li><a href="/page2"><img src="image2.jpg" title="title2" /></a></li>
<li><a href="/page3/14426"><img src="image3.jpg" title="title3" /></a></li>
<li><a href="/page4"><img src="image4.jpg" title="title4" /></a></li>
<li><img src="image5.jpg" title="title5" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

BX-slider settings: http://bxslider.com/options

ps. Is a fiddle needed to help me?

Comment: provide the jsfiddle

Comment: apperently the minSlide and maxSlide value where the same creation the strange behavior